# Edit fields in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am a beginner in Angularjs and was trying to implement edit of a field and trying to save the data..

The below is the html:-

```
<div class="row" ng-if="showme=='false'">
      <div class="myaddress">
        <div class="card-addresses">
          <div class="card card-address" ng-repeat="address in addresses" ng-click="selectAddress(address)" ng-class="{active : selectedAddress === address}">
            <div class="overlay">
              <div class="icon icon-approved"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-header">
              <div class="pull-left"><span>{{address.label}}</span></div>
              <div class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-click="editAddress(address)"></i>
                <div class="editpopup editpopup-{{istrue}}">
                  <p>edit id:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="address.street"/>
                  </p>
                  <p>edit pname:
                    <input type="text" ng-model="address.station"/>
                  </p>
                  <button ng-click="save()">save</button>
                  <button ng-click="closepopup()">cancel</button>
                </div>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="delAddress(address)"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <p>{{address.building}}</p>
              <p>{{address.street}}</p>
              <p>{{address.station}} {{address.city}} - {{address.pincode}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"><span>Default</span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" ng-click="addAddress()">Add New Address</button>
      </div>
```

The below is the js:-

```
$scope.editrow=function($index){
         $scope.istrue=true;
         $scope.$index = $index;
         angular.copy($scope.address[$index], $scope.address);
      }

      $scope.closepopup=function(){
         $scope.istrue=false;

      }

      $scope.save = function() {  
        $scope.istrue=false;
        angular.copy($scope.addresses, $scope.addresses[0]) 
        Address.save($scope.addresses)

    };
```

I am trying to fetch and save the data in the service Address which gets getting the value from the database

Comment: Whats is wrong and what is is that you need, exactly?

Comment: @acdcjunior I am trying to edit the fields which i am able to do with ng-model and getting the values in the scope of address but its not getting saved

Answer (score 0):

You need store edit state in each address

So html

```
  <div class="row" ng-if="showme=='false'">
  <div class="myaddress">
    <div class="card-addresses">
      <div class="card card-address" ng-repeat="address in addresses" ng-click="selectAddress(address)" ng-class="{active : selectedAddress === address}">
        <div class="overlay">
          <div class="icon icon-approved"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-header">
          <div class="pull-left"><span>{{address.label}}</span></div>
          <div class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-click="editAddress(address)"></i>
            <div class="editpopup editpopup-{{address.istrue}}">
              <p>edit id:
                <input type="text" ng-model="address.street"/>
              </p>
              <p>edit pname:
                <input type="text" ng-model="address.station"/>
              </p>
              <button ng-click="save(address)">save</button>
              <button ng-click="closepopup(address)">cancel</button>
            </div>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-trash" ng-click="delAddress(address)"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>{{address.building}}</p>
          <p>{{address.street}}</p>
          <p>{{address.station}} {{address.city}} - {{address.pincode}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer"><span>Default</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="button" ng-click="addAddress()">Add New Address</button>
  </div>
```

And js

```
  $scope.editrow=function($index){
     $scope.istrue=true;
     $scope.$index = $index;
     //angular.copy($scope.address[$index], $scope.address); // why you need this?
  }

  $scope.closepopup=function(address){
     address.istrue=false;

  }

  $scope.save = function() {  
    address.istrue=false;
    // angular.copy($scope.addresses, $scope.addresses[0])// why you need this?
    Address.save($scope.addresses)

};
```

Comment: The save is working but is creating another row that is it is adding instead of replacing